# Automating substitute expressions in vim

Tags: vim, command, substitution

What is a good way to automate substitute commands in vim?

Suppose I have something like:

```
s/foo/bar/g
```

except much more complex and I want to run it on selected ranges without 
having to type the substitute command?

How can I save the substitute command and give it short convenient name that I can invoke it by?

Comment: You may also look into auto commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function with range supported, and in the function do the substitution. Also create a custom command to call the function with range.

However the easiest way I think, is creating an `abbrev` in your vimrc file:

```
cab RR s/foo/bar/g
```

thus, when you selected lines, or in command line gave ranges (like `3,5 or % ...`) you press `RR<space>` the `s/foo/bar/g` will be filled automatically. You can do some adjustment or just press enter let it go.

Answer (score 1):

You could try mapping below pressing the space key twice  on a particular word will autofill the substitute command with the word under the cursor and wait for you to enter the replacement name

```
" super quick search and replace
nnoremap <Space><Space> :'{,'}s/\<<C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR>\>/
nnoremap <Space>%       :%s/\<<C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR>\>/
```

in your case just put the cursor on the foo word and press the space bar twice.
You should see

```
:'{,'}s/\<foo\>/
```

Then type the word bar

```
'{,'}s/\<foo\>/bar
```

all occurrences of foo will be replaced by bar